# Increase in internal energy and temperature

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, heat-transfer, thermal-insulation

A banquet hall (150 m3) is to be used for a formal dinner for 20 persons. Each person occupies 0.075 m3 of space and has an average heat transfer rate of 500 kJ/hr. If the AC system fails, determine the increase in the internal energy and temperature of air in the hall during the first 15 minutes of failure. Take the hall to be well insulated from outside. If the hall and all its contents are considered as system how much will be the increase in the internal energy of the system.

Comment: Looks like a good question, what have you done so far? This is not a free homework service.

Comment: @solar Mike I tried doing q=u+ w,q supplied assuming 500kj/hr × 15 min